# How to mark a jpeg file and save without loading all the bitmap

Tags: android, optimization, bitmap

I am working on an app where I take pictures and I need to write some text in the corner of the picture. I already have something that works that draws black text over a white rectangle:

```
private void tagPhoto(Bitmap bitmap){

    // Initiates paint object for canvas
    Paint p = getMarker();

    // Initialize canvas
    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    // Measure text
    p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textFrame); // textFrame is a Rect object

    // Draw frame for text
    tempCanvas.drawRect(0, 0,
            textFrame.width() + 2* MARGIN,  textFrame.height() + 2* MARGIN,
            p);

    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    // Write the mark on the canvas
    tempCanvas.drawText(text, MARGIN, textFrame.height() + MARGIN, p);

}
```

Then I save back the bitmap to the file it was. I am searching for optimizing this code.

While searching, I was searching and stumbled on `BitmapRegionDecoder` which help loading only part of a bitmap. I was wondering if I could use this and then save the modified part on the source bitmap without loading it on cache.

Or are there other methods I don't know about to mark a Jpeg file efficiently?

Comment: You will not be able to do exactly what you want to do. You could technically open the JPG and write back just the portions that changed, but that would be way more trouble than it's work I would think. Is there an issue with saving back the whole bitmap?

Comment: I get some `OutOfMemory` errors on some older devices. It would make two birds one stone